# grails: primary key from view

Tags: grails, view

I have a requirement to create Employee and Role domain with ids which should be inserted at the time of creation and not manually inserted via code.
Following is attached code for Role.groovy

```
package pocgrails1

class Role{

  String roleId
  String roleName
  static hasMany = [RoleACL]
  static mapping = {id generator: 'assigned',name:"roleId",type:'string'}
  static constraints = {
    roleName blank:false
    roleId blank:false

  }

  String toString(){
    return id
  }
```

}

I am having issues while generating the primary key from the view.
By default the scaffold does not generates the field to insert the primary key value.
I already have looked into several blogs and posts but none were of much help.
What should be the correct approach for this.

Many thanks in advance.

Rohit

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand what do you want to do. If you want to change primary id key define it as **String id** and **change mapping**:

```
class Role{
   String id

   static mapping = {
      id column: 'role_id', generator: 'assigned'
   }
}
```

When you save object an id will be generated for you and persisted to database, no need to create anything manually